# SSRS BIDS Placeholder line select in expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence, bids

I have an SSRS report with a very large text box. When the report is rendered the data may or may not use up the entire size of the textbox. I cannot have the box expand so I have the checkbox unchecked that will allow it to expand. Instead i would like to print the remaining text in a separate placeholder.

I want to know if there is a way in an expression to select a specific number of rows of text in a text box.

Comment: Similar question here with no good answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bee5f3e9-fd35-4607-a501-36578932d7fc/textbox-text-overflow